# Can't set TextBox.MinWidthProperty when creating a VisualTree for GridViewColumn.DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have am trying to set a GridViewColumn.DataTemplate to a TextBox VisualTree. The code so far is:

```
//GridViewColumnCollection columns
DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();
FrameworkElementFactory elementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
elementFactory.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("Position") });
elementFactory.SetValue(TextBox.MinWidthProperty, new GridLength(50));
template.VisualTree = elementFactory;
columns[1].CellTemplate = template;
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

> 50 is not a valid value for property 'MinWidth'.

on this line:
    `elementFactory.SetValue(TextBox.MinWidthProperty, new GridLength(50));`

I also tried setting the value to just 50, but to no avail!

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.minwidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the `MinWidth` dependency property is of type `double`. You should set it to a double instead of a `GridLength` object.

> Property Value
>
> Type: System.Double
>
> The minimum width of the element, in device-independent units (1/96th inch per unit). The default value is 0.0. This value can be any value equal to or greater than 0.0. However, PositiveInfinity is not valid, nor is Double.NaN.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. See edit.

Comment: You have to pass a `double`. If you write `50` that is an `int32`. Try writing `50.0`. Or better, pass a variable of type `double`.

Comment: I changed the value to 50d and it worked. Thanks very much. One would think that the inference engine is smarter than that! I am using C# 4.0 by the way.

Comment: The `FrameworkElementFactory.SetValue` method's second argument is of type `object`. It just takes that object and tries to update the dependency property. If it had to check the type of each object it receives against the type of object that the dependency property expects and then apply an appropriate conversion, that would involve a lot of work. Note that XAML has such an "inference engine", so it's usually not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I totally assent with bouvierr. I was working on a WPF project and this was something I also run into. Eventually, through the MSDN documentation, I noticed that the code behind concept only accepts double data type as supposed to an integer.

```
textBox.SetValue(HeightProperty, 120.0);
textBox.SetValue(WidthProperty, 360.0);
textBox.SetValue(FontSizeProperty, 14.0);
textBox.SetValue(MinWidthProperty, 50.0);
```